# Contradictory values when logging object and object.key side by side

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise

I have two console.log statements, one after the other. The first logs an entire object, `elem`, and the second logs the `elem.hero`. This is the result I get:

```
//console.dir(elem)
{ 
    project: {}, 
    hero: {
        path: "569f9dcbe4b0ea7fccac85b4/569f9dd5e4b060eb54c0dd7c",
        fileType:"png"
    }
}

//console.dir(elem.hero)
{ 
    path: "default",
    fileType:"jpg"        
}
```

Image of it here:

[image]

In other words, inspecting the `elem` object's hero property gives me what I expect, but logging it's value directly to the console gives me an old value. What's going on here? Here's my relevant code.

```js
var projects = []

function getProjects() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var url = "http://example.com/api/v2/projects"
    utils.sendAPIRequest(url, utils.generateToken(), function(err, data, xhr){
      if(err) {
        reject(Error(err))
      }
      else {
        for(var i in data) {
          projects.push({project: data[i], hero: { path: "default", fileType: "jpg"}})
        }
        resolve() 
      }      
    })
  })
}

function constructHeroURL(elem){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var url = 'http://example.com/api/v2/files?size=1&query=meta.image.ExecPortalArtistImage_1445947066011:Yes+AND+project._id:' + elem.project.id 
    utils.sendAPIRequest(url, utils.generateToken(), function(err, data, xhr){
      if(err) {
        reject(Error(err))
      }
      else {
        for(var i in data) {
          var id = data[i].id
          var fileID = data[i].revisions[0].preview[0].fileID
          var fileType = data[i].revisions[0].preview[0].name.split('.')
          elem.hero.path = id + '/' + fileID
          elem.hero.fileType = fileType[fileType.length-1]
        }
        resolve() 
      }      
    })    
  })
}

function getHeroImages(elem){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.dir(elem) // logs in question
    console.dir(elem.hero) // on these lines
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/media/' + elem.hero.path
    $.get(url)
    .done(function(data, status, xhr){
      resolve(data) 
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, err){
      reject(Error(err))   
    })    
  })  
}

getProjects()
.then(function(){
  return projects.map(constructHeroURL)
})
.then(function(){
  return projects.map(getHeroImages)
  .reduce(function(sequence, imagePromise) {
    // Use reduce to chain the promises together,
    // adding content to the page for each chapter
    return sequence.then(function() {
      // Wait for everything in the sequence so far,
      // then wait for this chapter to arrive.
      return imagePromise
    }).then(function(image) {
      console.log(image)
    })
  }, Promise.resolve())
})
```

Comment: Can you wrap your result in question instead of external image ? I am unable to access it(n/w restrictions) :(

Comment: @RayonDabre Absolutely, One sec

Comment: Have you chained your promises ? One after other ? I guess there are being called multiple times..

Comment: @RayonDabre They're being called once for each object, each `console.log` statement is firing once and once only. Let me include my chain...

Comment: Can you show us how they are executed/invoked ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is cause properties of `elem.hero` have [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) but property `hero` of `elem` has [reference type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

So result of `console.log(elem.hero);` shows its property value (primitives) and `console.log(elem);` shows reference to its property `hero`, which is updated after successful request.

Comment: `elem.hreo` is an object which is not a primitive value type.

Comment: Yes, but it seems `console.log` displays properties of an object.